# R: Using relative importance (relaimpo package) to build a linear model for prediction?

Tags: r, statistics

I have a huge dataset and I'm trying to build a good predictive linear model using the relaimpo package.

Using the `calc.relimp` function with `type="lmg`, i get an output of variables which are of relative importance. Although the proportion of variance explained by the model is only at 52%, I want to go and build a linear model using these variables.

Is there a way to build a `lm` model using these variables and somehow take into account the relative importance values into the model?

*I'm not too familiar with this and was thinking maybe something along the lines of weighting each variable based on its relative importance value...?*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a statistician, so I won't give you any Greek symbols, but I think you are confusing a few things.

- As you correctly say, the relative importances based on the LMG method are more or less some sort of variance decomposition in case of correlated predictor variables, i.e. it tells you how much of your variance in the model is explained by which predictor.
- However, this doesn't have to do anything with the `lm` function and its estimation itself. In fact, the R² of your `lm` model is exactly the same as you'll get by summing up the relative importances from `calc.relimp`.
- There is no way to tell the `lm` function to pay more attention to a certain predictor during prediction/estimation.
- What you probably want to do is an elastic net (which is a combination of LASSO and RIDGE regression), which basically does what you want, i.e. it shrinks the impact of "unimportant"/small predictors and emphasizes the impact of important/large predictors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization (Lasso and Ridge regression are linked in the Wikipedia article).
- I think this one here is the original package from Jerome Friedman, Trevor Hastie, Rob Tibshirani, et al.: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html